# PrimeFaces v3.4 ++: Datatable sorting is not working properly

Tags: java, sorting, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have the following simple test page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="container">
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable id="unusedTable" var="c" value="#{couponBean.unusedCoupons}"
                                 paginator="true" rows="5">

                    <p:column headerText="#{l10n.id}" sortBy="#{c.id}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.id}" />  
                    </p:column> 

                    <p:column headerText="#{l10n.name}" sortBy="#{c.name}" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.name}" /> 
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I deploy the app using PrimeFaces v3.4.2 or v3.5, I observe the following weird behaviour:

- Originally:
  [image: Before sorting]
- After sorting:
  [image: After sorting]

As you can see, originally, the table appeared with the sorting icons on the left of the table. If I try to sort any columns, the sorted table is generated on the 1st column of the original table.

I tried to re-deploy my app using PrimeFaces v3.3.1 and everything works perfectly.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me how to tackle this problem.

Best regards,

James Tran

Comment: I can see only two columns in your code. Can you provide more complete code sample?

Comment: @jedrus07: I have updated my question with proper pictures. Other codes does not cause this problem. :)

Comment: Are you using pure JSF on server? If you have Spring MVC/webflow this can cause problems with PF partial rendering

Comment: @rootkit: I am testing the page locally. Besides, I also do not use Spring :)

Comment: can you show your `couponBean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project suddenly got corrupted. I have no idea why it happened. However, after I created a new project and copied all the files over, sorting with PrimeFaces v3.4+++ works normally again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a rowKey attribute in your datatable. rowKey="#{c.id}"

Comment: `rowKey` is for selecting but I tried anyway and it still doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea- what class is `unusedCoupons`? Is it sortable? If not (or even if it is). Just try adding an `ArrayList` with your items in `filteredValue=`. This is reqired for filtering (because it creates a place for storing your temporary filtered data) and it may well be used for sorting as well.

**Extra information**

I have working `p:dataTable` on my primefaces 3.4++ with sorting. The differences that I see are that to define header text I use:

```
<p:column sortBy="#{c.id}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{l10n.id}" />   
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{c.id}" />
</p:column>
```

Instead of yours `headerText`=.

Also all my columns have `id`'s assigned. Other than that it is the same (plus I have filtering) and it works without problems.

Comment: :) It still doesn't work

Comment: are c.id and c.name just Strings? What scope is couponBean?

Comment: The bean is `@ViewScoped` and both the parameters are String

Comment: Annotation '@ViewScope' is broken in many JSF implementation (if you are not using CODI or Seam). Can you try to change the scope to '@ApplicationScope' just to test if this is related?

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by that annotation. It worked with PrimeFaces v3.3.1. :S